# How to make sure the texture doesn't stretch on the inside of a cylinder?

Tags: texturing, uv-image-editor

I've been trying to put a brick texture on a cylinder, I'm running out of time since I've been stuck on this for so long. The sides as shown in the picture below are getting stretched out, I've tried UV mapping and scaling though I don't completely understand it yet so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. (The wall in the back and the cylinder are separated objects.) I also have tried the overlays>stretching and Minimize Stretch and Average Islands Scale.
[image]

When I try to do cylinder projection it looks like the picture below.
[image]

I'm using blender 2.8. Really thankful for quick answer.

Comment: it's not clear what you're trying to do, could you please show your Shader Editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try this?

Use UV texture coordinates as input into mapping, then it should work:

[image]

[image]

Note: i did not unwrap it at all, but if you already did, go to UV Editing tab, press A to select all vertices, then UV -> Smart UV Project

Comment: This worked, although there's an edge that cuts the texture so it doesn't line up. How do I get rid of it?

Comment: did you apply scale and rotation on your cylinder? if yes, a blend file would help. But of course you can "play" with the y scale value of the mapping node to make it fit, you can also "play" with the scale value of the brick texture

Answer (score 3):

Welcome. It looks like you are having some trouble with UV unwrapping.

You'll want to mark seams on the end rings of your cylinder and then resize each of these UV 'islands' to correct the scale and 'stretching' of the bricks.

[image]

1. Alt+L-Click to select the ring at each end of your cylinder.
2. Ctrl+E opens the Edge menu, Select Mark Seam. This change will take effect in the UV Editor window.

[image]

3. Press A to select all, in the 3D viewport window
4. In the UV Editor hover over each UV 'island' and press L to select connected vertices.
5. Press S to scale and drag the mouse. L-Click to set the change. If you have a seamless texture you can scale the UV islands larger than your texture and it will repeat.
6. Switch to Rendered view in the 3d Viewport window and you can see the changes take effect as you rescale.

[image]

7. Make sure your texture is applied in the Shader Editor. With the Principled BSDF selected you can press Ctrl+Shift+T to import a Principled Shader setup and it will automatically connect all the nodes for you. (Note: You must have the Node Wrangler Add-On enabled in Preferences for this shortcut to work).

Hope that helps.